# How to write Python doctest that is OS independent regarding path separator

Tags: python-2.6, doctest

Is there a way to have a doctest with file paths as output that will succeed regardless of the OS it's run on?

For example, on Windows this will work:

```
r"""
>>> import foo
>>> relative_path = foo.getRelativePath()
>>> print relative_path 
'bar\\foobar'
"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from doctest import testmod
    print testmod()
```

But of course will fail on Linux and produce an error similar to:

```
Failed example:
    print relative_path 
Expected:
    'bar\\foobar'
Got:
    'bar/foobar'
```

How can I make the above work on any OS?

**EDIT**

I know I can do something like this instead:

```
>>> relative_path == os.path.join('bar', 'foobar')
True
```

But I'm wondering if there is a different and better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Clarification**

Doctests are alluring because of their simplicity, but it's a misleading simplicity. You expect the test line to represent an expression that doctest will evaluate against the result of the last expression, but it's not; it's actually just doing a simple, basic string comparison.

```
#doctesttest.py
"""
>>> "test"
"test"

python -m doctest doctesttest.py
```

Gives

```
...
Expected:
    "test"
Got:
    'test'
```

Although - in pythonic terms - `"test" == 'test'`, even `"test" is 'test'`, `str(""" 'test' """)` does not match `str(""" "test" """)`.

Armed with this awareness...

**Solution**

The following will fail on all systems:

```
def unique_paths(path_list):
    """ Returns a list of normalized-unique paths based on path_list
    >>> unique_paths(["first/path", ".\\first/path", "second/path"])
    ['first/path', 'second/path']
    """

    return set(os.path.normpath(p) for p in path_list)
```

1. We got a set, not a list,
2. Converting the set into a list needs to provide a consistent order,
3. doctest uses *eval* so the "\" in ".\first" will be converted into "\".

We're looking for a simple string match, so we need to look for an easily matchable result *string*. You don't care about the separator, so either eliminate it or replace it, or test around it:

```
def unique_paths(path_list):
    """ Returns a list of normalized-unique paths based on path_list
    >>> paths = unique_paths(["first/path", ".\\\\first/path", "second/path"])
    >>> len(paths)
    2
    >>> [os.path.split(path) for path in sorted(list(paths))]
    [('first', 'path'), ('second', 'path')]
    # or heck, even
    >>> sorted(list(paths[0])).replace('\\\\', '/')
    'first/path'
    """
    return set(os.path.normpath(p) for p in path_list)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can get the os-dependent path separator by calling

```
sep = os.sep
```

and then process your relative paths for the platform you are working on. Or you can use

```
os.abspath()
```

instead. There are various options ( see http://pymotw.com/2/ospath/ ). I took the abspath-variant.

-Kim

Comment: My question is about path separators in **doctest** output, not Python in general.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score -3):

just ditch the pathname manipulation functions (`os.path.join`, `os.path.split`, etc).  can you name a situation where `/` will not work?  in my experience, those are few and far between, and all in the context of invoking windows-native programs in *cmd.exe* or *command.com* (those programs typically use `/` for options).  outside of this particular scenario, forward slashes work in most situations in windows, and i'm willing to bet you're not targetting VAX/VMS.

Comment: The OP was asking about tests, your answer indicates that in 2014 you may have needed to learn a lot more about testing. Non-/ separators can be introduced from all kinds of places:

a) file content, b) user input, c) system() calls and pipe reads, d) sys.path, e) os.walk, f) fuse file systems, ...